# swiftUI list row in NavigationLink default padding some pix?

Tags: list, swiftui, label, swiftui-navigationlink

...

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Rectangle().fill(Color.black).ignoresSafeArea(edges:Edge.Set.bottom)
        List() {
            ForEach(viewModel.list!) { item in
                if item.index == 0 {
                    SettingRow(info: item)
                        .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                        .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 10))
                }else{
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("测试")) {
                        SettingRow(info: item)
                            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                            .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 10)).labelStyle(TitleOnlyLabelStyle())
                    }.listRowBackground(Color.clear).padding(0)
                }
            }
        }.listStyle(PlainListStyle()).padding(.top,10)
    }
}
```

...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFV2v.png)
what happen?

If I didn't use NavigationLink, it worked fine, but once I joined it, the layout shifted a few pixels to the left and right. I tried adjusting the pad, but it didn't work. I didn't know what to do. I tried to upload the row width using ‘GeometryReader ‘and the display was normal. I think the ’label‘  was faulty.  Is there a fixed offset? Anybody know?

Comment: Can you please create a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?